# OledbDataReader getOrdinal Issue

Tags: vb.net, oledbdatareader

I have some problem with the function GetOrdinal coming from the OleDb.DataReader. In my table, I have columns named with some space.
I tried to call it with some [ ]:

`Dim dr as System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
dr.GetOrdinal("[Nom truc]")`

but it's telling me : "IndexOutOfRangeException"

I can't change the name of the field. The type of my base is accdb. In Microsoft Access, my query is working.

Sorry for my poor english, I'm an France girl :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the brackets:

```vb
'dr.GetOrdinal("[Nom truc]")
dr.GetOrdinal("Nom truc")
```

Comment: It's not working because I am using the request to set up an OleDbCommand: <br/> `Dim c as System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select [nom truc] from machin") <br/> c.ExecuteReader()`<br/> Without the brackets I have a syntax exception. So I tried to put the brackets in c and remove then from the dr.GetOrdinal but it return nothing.

Comment: @MlleStrife You keep the brackets in your sql, you lose the brackets in your GetOrdinal function. If it returns nothing, then you have no data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working! :) I made a mistake in my field name when I tried to print the return of GetOrdinal... I'm so clumsy! Thanks again for your quick answer!